# How to increase the speed of loading images to UIImageView using AFNetworking in iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, afnetworking, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView and inside the CollectionView cell it has a UIImageView.
I used AFNetworking to load images from web service.But it takes much more time to load data.Is there any way to speed up this process. I have attached my code.
hope your help.

//loading data

```
- (void)loadcategoryData
{
    post = nil;
    NSString *mainurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some url"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:mainurl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        posts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        post = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(NSDictionary *all in posts)
        {
            Categories *category = [Categories new];
            category.title = [all objectForKey:@"catname"];
            category.firsturl = [all objectForKey:@"url"];

            [self.maincollectionView reloadData];
            //call for images

            imagespost = nil;
            NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", category.firsturl];
            AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *managerone = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            [managerone GET:imageUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {



                imagesposts = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
                NSArray *resultone = [imagesposts objectForKey:@"posts"];
                imagespost = [NSMutableArray array];
                if ([resultone count]) {
                    NSDictionary *firstpost = resultone[0];
//                    Categories *newmogocat = [Categories new];

                    NSDictionary *thumbnail_images = [firstpost objectForKeyedSubscript:@"thumbnail_images"];
                    NSDictionary *thumbnail = [thumbnail_images objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
                    category.imageOneUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnail objectForKey:@"url"]];
//                    NSLog(@"%@", newmogocat.imageOneUrl);
//                    [imagespost addObject:newmogocat];

                    [post addObject:category];

                    [self.maincollectionView reloadData];
                }

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            }];


        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError * responseObject) {

    }];
}
```

// assign values to collectionview cell

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategoryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellidentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;


    [cell addSubview:cell.maintitleLabel];

    Categories *cat = [post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.maincollectionView reloadInputViews];
    cell.maintitleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", cat.title];
    [cell.maintitleLabel sizeToFit];






    NSString *mainstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cat.imageOneUrl];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mainstring];
//    NSLog(@"%@", mainstring);


    [cell.mainImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];




    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h) as it is smart enough to cache images fetched from same url.

Comment: yes, I'm using it , but it take more time to load images.What can I do for that. @ozgur

Comment: @anuk -- your coding is fine , compare to UIImageView+AFNetworking.h  use sdwebimage its very faster, else part u need to use blocks for this

Comment: thanx @Anbu.Karthik . I'll use it next time

Comment: Instead of attempting to download and load the image when the collectionView needs cells, I would first download all the images I need and only load up the collectionView when all the images become available

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30014631/3408316

Answer (score 0):

Import "UIImage + AfNetworking.h"

Inside `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cat.imageOneUrl]];
[EDIT] : 
 __weak CategoryCollectionViewCell *weakCell = cell; [EDIT]
[cell.articleThumbnail setImageWithURLRequest:req placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
   [EDIT] weakCell.articleThumbnail.image = image;
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    [EDIT] weakCell.articleThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
}];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm working on it. I do not have enough reputations to voteup, I'will do it whenever possible. sorry for that. thanx again @Saheb Roy

Comment: yeah no problem mate. as long as it helps :)

Comment: @ Saheb Roy, there is a warning called "Capturing 'cell' strongly in this block is likely to lead to retain cycle' when i call

cell.mainimageView.image = image;

Comment: this is not working @Saheb Roy, anyway thanx for your help